# Algebra in von Neumann analysis for PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In my PDEs class, von Neumann analysis was introduced as a tool to show Lax-Richtmyer stability. We considered vectors $v_k$ with elements

$$v_{k,m} = \exp\left(2ik\pi\frac{m\Delta x}{D}\right)$$

for $k, m \in \{0, ..., M-1\}$, and were told that the vectors satisfy $v_k^* v_l = 0$ if $k \neq l$. Here $\Delta x = 1/M$ is the grid spacing.

I was not able to show $v_k^* v_l = 0$, but it should just involve some algebra.

Comment: I assume $v_k^* v_l$ is meant to be the standard inner product given by

$$ v_k^* v_l = \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} \overline{v_{k,m}} v_{l,m}.$$

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes.

Comment: So I would drop the $\Delta x$ notation in favor of $\frac{1}{M}$ for starters (why carry around an extra variable that seems different but really isn't?). Your inner product is then

$$v_k^* v_l = \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} \exp\left(2\pi i (k-l) \frac{m}{MD}\right).$$

What is $D$ here? I am reminded of the identity $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \omega^k = 0$ where $\omega$ is an $n$th root of unity with this identity, but $D$ complicates matters.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I think $D$ is just a constant.